# Creating a replace function to replace HTML characters (scraping project - BeautifulSoup - Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a scraping project but I'm unsure about the best way to code the character replacement part (using the "replace" function) for each card I'm parsing so that I don't have to keep repeating the "replace" function for each type of replacement I'm doing. Does anyone know the best way to make this work?

Example (room):

```
room=[]        # list
 
for i in range(pages):
    url = 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/rj/rio-de-janeiro/?pagina='+str(i+1)
    driver.get(url)
    
    
    data = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    
    
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.encode('utf-8'), "lxml")
    
    
    
    anuncios = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'results-list js-results-list'}).find_all(class_="js-card-selector")

   
    
    for line in anuncios:


            full_room=line.find(class_="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms").text.strip()
            full_room=full_room.replace(' ','')
            full_room=full_room.replace('\n','')
            full_room=full_room.replace('Quartos','')
            full_room=full_room.replace('Quarto','')
            room.append(full_room)
```

Comment: Use the `re` module to shorten all the `replace()`

Comment: I am just starting to use Python and study scraping, so I don't know exactly how to do this. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What does `line.find(class_="property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms").text.strip()` returns? What is your expected string to append to the list?

Comment: text.strip() returns the string located within html that I specified with the ".find" function. In this case, returns >2 rooms<

Comment: I'm trying to get the string inside this HTML for all pages, replacing characters like /n and " ", but I'm trying to find a way to do this without having to keep repeating replace function

Comment: @Mari what you are looking to extract from listing ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `selenium` for such case, your desired data is actually presented within `HTML` source, I've picked up it using `regex` and then parsed it with `Json` module.

Here's the full scheme of single page --> [click-here](http://jsonblob.com/933093739233296384)

```py
import json
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for page in range(1, 3):
            params = {
                'pagina': page
            }
            print(f'Extracting Page# {page}')
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            match = re.search(
                'Initialization.*\r?\n[^\[]*\[(.+\})\]', r.text).group(1)
            target = json.loads(match)
            for item in target['search']['result']['listings']:
                print(item['listing']['title'])


main('https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/rj/rio-de-janeiro/')
```

Comment: `Initialization.*?\[(.+\})\]` with [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag should be more efficient. [*Benchmark code*](https://cutt.ly/HIRUfjB).